# using cpd on python

Tags: python, cpd

I am trying to run the GUI version of CPD on my python codebase, but no duplicate code is returned even when i set the min chunk size to 1.

My code isnt that good.

has anyone ever had any success running CPD on a python project?

Comment: Could you show your current configuration for CPD?

Answer (score 2):

Python is natively supported since PMD v5.3.0 (January 2015) : https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd-python/index.html
It can be run like this :

> .\cpd.bat --minimum-tokens 75 --files C:\Path\to\your\project\ --language python

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you with CPD.  Consider trying our [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) duplicate code detector. It has a Python front end, and there are sample results from clone detection runs at the site.   Pretty much CloneDR manages to find clones in everybody's code, especially if it "isn't that good".

Comment: nice, i will evaluate it. I got emailed a download link with an exe, but the trouble is that we use osx at work! ill try it at home though

Comment: No guarantees, but our tools do seem to work under Wine on OSX.